# Second transaction remains waiting after the first completes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, locks

Running this same script in 2 windows in SSMS one after another with a couple of seconds' delay.
The second instance that I start later completes but the first one remains locked till I close the second window.
What is happening here? Why is it not releasing the lock after the COMMIT?

```
SET TRAN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * FROM dbo.t1
WHERE id IN (1,3)

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20'

UPDATE t1 SET InUse=0
WHERE id IN (1,3)

COMMIT
```

**Edit:**

The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [InUse] [BIT] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: I get the expected deadlock error when I run your script on 2 different sessions. My guess is that the second session already had an open transaction so it was not actually committed (only decrementing the transaction count), blocking the first until the second was closed and rolled back. Try adding `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;` to the beginning of the script.

Comment: Thanks! I got the dedlock failure the first time but on subseqent runs the first transaction just kept waiting. Now I can consistently reproduce the deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your question with the table structure.

As you did not specify whether your table has any index on it I assume there hasn't, i.e. `dbo.t1` is a `heap`.

In this case you'll get classic `deadlock`:

`session1` wants to `select` from table and needs `S` for any row it reads and because there is no `index` on `dbo.t1` the whole table is read and `S-lock` on the table is held for the whole duration of the transaction.

In meanwhile `session2` does the same and it also acquires `S-lock` on the table and holds it.

`Session1` now needs to convert its `S-lock` to `IX` in order to do `update` and it is blocked by `session2` that holds `S` on `dbo.t1`.

When `session2` tries to do the same it leads to deadlock because both sessions need `IX` and both are locked by other session.

Here is the corresponding deadlock graph:

```
deadlock-list
 deadlock victim=process155d1d498
  process-list
   process id=process155d1d498 taskpriority=0 logused=0 waitresource=OBJECT: 26:1765581328:0  waittime=16222 ownerId=5528849 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2019-02-07T13:39:38.837 XDES=0x15ec1c3a8 lockMode=IX schedulerid=4 kpid=8140 status=suspended spid=54 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2019-02-07T13:39:38.833 lastbatchcompleted=2019-02-07T13:39:38.833 lastattention=2019-02-07T13:38:49.187 clientapp=Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query hostname=pppp hostpid=12276 loginname=FINCONSGROUP\anna.savchenko isolationlevel=serializable (4) xactid=5528849 currentdb=26 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671098976 clientoption2=390200
    executionStack
     frame procname=adhoc line=9 stmtstart=248 stmtend=334 sqlhandle=0x02000000f445021276fec0f5ec119082f65611ce316a4d280000000000000000000000000000000000000000
UPDATE t1 SET InUse=0
WHERE id IN (1,3)     
    inputbuf
SET TRAN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT * FROM dbo.t1
WHERE id IN (1,3)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20'
UPDATE t1 SET InUse=0
WHERE id IN (1,3)
COMMIT
   process id=process15649f868 taskpriority=0 logused=0 waitresource=OBJECT: 26:1765581328:0  waittime=1212 ownerId=5529084 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2019-02-07T13:39:53.847 XDES=0x15ec1d048 lockMode=IX schedulerid=3 kpid=15516 status=suspended spid=57 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2019-02-07T13:39:53.847 lastbatchcompleted=2019-02-07T13:39:53.847 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.847 clientapp=Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query hostname=pppp hostpid=12276 loginname=FINCONSGROUP\anna.savchenko isolationlevel=serializable (4) xactid=5529084 currentdb=26 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671098976 clientoption2=390200
    executionStack
     frame procname=adhoc line=9 stmtstart=248 stmtend=334 sqlhandle=0x0200000093b3ba1c08d586d1f142f473a7c8996074a369fc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
UPDATE t1 SET InUse=0
WHERE id IN (1,3)     
    inputbuf
SET TRAN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT * FROM dbo.t1
WHERE id IN (1,3)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20'
UPDATE t1 SET InUse=0
WHERE id IN (1,3)
COMMIT    
  resource-list
   objectlock lockPartition=0 objid=1765581328 subresource=FULL dbid=26 objectname=parts.dbo.t1 id=lock152c2d300 mode=S associatedObjectId=1765581328
    owner-list
     owner id=process15649f868 mode=S
     owner id=process15649f868 mode=IX requestType=convert
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process155d1d498 mode=IX requestType=convert
   objectlock lockPartition=0 objid=1765581328 subresource=FULL dbid=26 objectname=parts.dbo.t1 id=lock152c2d300 mode=S associatedObjectId=1765581328
    owner-list
     owner id=process155d1d498 mode=S
     owner id=process155d1d498 mode=IX requestType=convert
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process15649f868 mode=IX requestType=convert
```